# 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:

Tags: .net, dapper

I'm creating an application in .net 7, using dapper in the layers pattern, Apresetation, Application, Domain, Infra

.net 7 doesn't have startup.cs to do the injections, I'm doing them in program.cs.

when my service (Application) calls my Domain, the injection error occurs, but it has been done.

Program.cs

```
using Ecommerce.Application.Services;
using Ecommerce.Application.Services.Interfaces;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();  
// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IFazerPedidoService, FazerPedidoService>();
//builder.Services.AddScoped<IFazerPedidoDomainService, FazerPedidoDomainService>();

var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Sevice

```
 public class FazerPedidoService : IFazerPedidoService
 {
     private readonly IFazerPedidoDomainService _fazerPedidoDomainService;
     public FazerPedidoService()
     {
     }

     public FazerPedidoModel FazerPedido(FazerPedidoModel fazerPedidoModel)
     {
         var pedido = new FazerPedidoEntity
         {
             Id = 999
         };

         pedido = _fazerPedidoDomainService.FazerPedidoDomain(pedido);
         return fazerPedidoModel;
     }
 }
```

```
namespace Ecommerce.Domain.Interfaces
{
    public interface IFazerPedidoDomainService
    {
        public FazerPedidoEntity FazerPedidoDomain(FazerPedidoEntity fazerPedidoEntity);
    }
}
```

I need to make this call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well no, they are not OK.

As I mentioned, you must ensure that you inject **all of your services**, at any level, not just the top level one.

Instead of

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFazerPedidoService, FazerPedidoService>();
```

Do this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFazerPedidoService, FazerPedidoService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFazerPedidoDomainService, FazerPedidoDomainService>();
// Assuming you have FazerPedidoRepository class here
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFazerPedidoRepository, FazerPedidoRepository >();
```

*(And change them back to `AddScoped()`, it should work perfectly fine)*

---

Explanation:

Look at how you are injecting the `IFazerPedidoService`. There are 2 steps:

1. Register the dependency in the `Program.cs`
2. Pass it via the constructor to the caller interface (in your case it's a controller).

You need to follow the same pattern for any other service you have, regardless of where you are consuming it (i.e. controller or other injected service).

In your case C# DI (dependency injection) has no clue how to 'enable' the `IFazerPedidoService`, because it cannot recognize the `IFazerPedidoDomainService`, which cannot recognize the `IFazerPedidoRepository` . Do you see the pattern?

Inject all the way down, all the necessary services and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have couple problems here.

1. You are not consuming injected dependency(ies). This is the correct way to consume it:

```cs
 public class FazerPedidoService : IFazerPedidoService
 {
     private readonly IFazerPedidoDomainService _fazerPedidoDomainService;

     // "Request" dependencies by passing them to the constructor
     // [optionally] then assign them to a private field
     public FazerPedidoService(IFazerPedidoDomainService fazerPedidoDomainService)
     {
_fazerPedidoDomainService = fazerPedidoDomainService;
     }
```

Explanation:

You are registering dependencies correctly in your `Program.cs`, but you want to 'consume' the interface by passing it via the constructor (and assigning it to the field, so that it can be reused in your methods). This way, when your service will first get accesses / created / called (depending on the scope), dependency injection will look at your mappings you done in `Program.cs`, and using reflection create an instance of `IFazerPedidoDomainService`.

*Note: if you need access to multiple services, just pass them to the constructor and separate by comma (,)*

2. You are missing a dependency (or its accidentally commented out).

```cs
// Uncomment this line
builder.Services.AddScoped<IFazerPedidoDomainService, FazerPedidoDomainService>();
```

Explanation:
You are expecting `IFazerPedidoDomainService` inside `FazerPedidoService`, thus, you should have a dependency injection for both of them (which seems that you used to had, you just commented it out).

---

With these changes it should work.

Comment: when I make this injection using the constructor and add it to program.cs, the following error appears when it is executed.

ServiceType: Ecommerce.Application.Services.Interfaces.IFazerPedidoService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Ecommerce.Application.Services.FazerPedidoService': Unable to resolve service for type

Comment: This error means that .NET dependency injection system encountered a dependency that it doesn't know how to resolve. I would try 3 things: 1) ensure that you have injected ALL dependencies (i.e.  `IFazerPedidoDomainService` may have more dependencies which you forgot to inject) 2) ensure that you don't have recursive dependencies (i.e. ServiceA requires ServiceB, and ServiceB requires ServiceA) 3) double-check how you are calling this service (i.e. calling Scoped service from Singleton may cause this error). You could try to change lifetimes to Singleton and observe the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked all the dependencies and they're all OK, here's the solution.

Program.cs

```html
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();  
// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IFazerPedidoService, FazerPedidoService>();

var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Controller

```html
     public class FazerPedidosController : ControllerBase
 {
     private readonly IFazerPedidoService _fazerPedidoService;
     public FazerPedidosController(IFazerPedidoService fazerPedidoService)
     {
         _fazerPedidoService = fazerPedidoService;
     }

     [HttpPost("FazerPedido")]
     public IActionResult FazerPedido(FazerPedidoModel fazerPedidoModel)
     {
         var retorno = _fazerPedidoService.FazerPedido(fazerPedidoModel);
         return Ok(retorno);
     }
 }
```

Service

```html
public class FazerPedidoService : IFazerPedidoService
{
    private readonly IFazerPedidoDomainService _fazerPedidoDomainService;
    public FazerPedidoService()
    {
    }

    public FazerPedidoModel FazerPedido(FazerPedidoModel fazerPedidoModel)
    {
        var pedido = new FazerPedidoEntity
        {
            Id = 999,
            Usuario = "Teste",
            DataPedido = DateTime.Now,
            Status = 2,
            TipoPedido = 3
        };

        pedido = _fazerPedidoDomainService.FazerPedidoDomain(pedido);
        return fazerPedidoModel;
    }
}
```

IFazerPedidoDomainService

```html
    public interface IFazerPedidoDomainService
{
    public FazerPedidoEntity FazerPedidoDomain(FazerPedidoEntity fazerPedidoEntity);
}
```

FazerPedidoDomainService

```html
    public class FazerPedidoDomainService : IFazerPedidoDomainService
{
    private IFazerPedidoRepository _repository;
    
    public FazerPedidoDomainService(IFazerPedidoRepository fazerPedidoRepository)
    {
        _repository = fazerPedidoRepository;  
    }

    public FazerPedidoEntity FazerPedidoDomain(FazerPedidoEntity fazerPedidoEntity)
    {
        return _repository.FazerPedidoDomain(fazerPedidoEntity);
    }
}
```